# Django DRF list of ids object

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have such serializers

```
   class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

        class Meta:
            model = MyModel
            fields = ('id',)

    class MyModelIdListSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
         ids = MyModelSerializer(many=True)
```

And request body like

```
{
    "ids": [
        {
            "id": "f07e3673-6631-4139-90da-331773ba868e"
        },
        {
            "id": "f07e3673-6631-4139-90da-331773ba868e"
        }
    ]
}
```

But need this

```
{
    "ids": [
         "f07e3673-6631-4139-90da-331773ba868e",
         "f07e3673-6631-4139-90da-331773ba868e"
    ]
}
```

I can do ListField with UUID as child but need to write custom validate if such id exists on table

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want list of `ids` use [**`PrimaryKeyRelatedField`**](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield)

```
ids = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, works for me. 
`class MyModelIdSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    ids = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True,
        queryset=MyModel.objects.all()
    )`

Comment: Cool answer. For my situation, I write my code as `contributor_ids = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=GithubContributor.objects.all())`